# ngModel not working in a input from user when getting it as an array

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my Html code
I have skipped some codes and I have entered the rest and the error is below please check and tell me sir/mam

here, `ngModel` is not working
I am trying to get an input from user and assign it as `v[number]` array
and later trying to bind the value but its not working
`ngModel` not accepting the number array

```html
       <ion-item>
          <ion-button *ngIf="hell" (click)="CreateRecord()" [disabled]="false">
            <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
            &nbsp;CreateRecord
          </ion-button>
          <ion-button *ngIf="!hell"(click)="CreateRecord()">
            <ion-icon size="small" slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
            &nbsp;HideRecord
          </ion-button>
        </ion-item>
        
        <ng-container *ngIf="!hell">
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              
              <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 40px;">Sno</ion-col>
              <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 180px;">Subject</ion-col>
              <ion-col style="font-size: larger;margin-left: 250px;" >Mark</ion-col>
            
                  
            </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        
    
        <ng-container *ngFor="let num of subject;let i=index">
          <ion-grid>
          <ion-row> 
            <ion-col><ion-card ><ion-input value="{{i+1}}"></ion-input></ion-card></ion-col>
            <ion-col><ion-card ><ion-input type ="text-only"></ion-input></ion-card></ion-col>
            *<ion-col><ion-card ><ion-input type ="number" [(ngModel)]="v[number]"></ion-input></ion-card>*</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          </ion-grid></ng-container>
```

error is there inside this tag * marked in star symbol, please check three lines above.

Here is my typscript for it

```typescript
    export class MarklistPage implements OnInit {
    
    subject:number[];hell:boolean = true;n=1;index:any;
      constructor() { }
    
    v1:number[];v:number[]=Array(100);
      
    ngOnInit() {
    
      }
      CreateRecord(){
    this.hell=!this.hell;
    }
    
     
      addForm(){
        this.n++;
      this.subject = Array(this.n).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
      }
     
      subForm(){
      
        this.subject = Array(this.n).splice(this.index,this.n--);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you want that to be `v[i]`. `number` doesn't exist as a variable (neither template nor ts). Btw. showing the error would be helpful.

Comment: @pravin, you need dive value to v1 also. NOTE. I think that you can give value only as array -it's not necesary indicate the "dimension"s, but I'm not pretty sure: `v1:number[]=[];v:number[]=[];`

Comment: thank you sir, i will try it my code and revert you back soon, thanks once again sir